# Symfony 5 support planed?

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony5

i work on symfony 5 and i wanne use sonata admin like in all other projects. Is there any upcoming release planed, that sonata admin is installable under symfony 5 with composer?

Comment: This is not a question for stack overflow, you would be better off getting in touch with the library owners or software owners

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
composer require sonata-project/user-bundle --no-update
composer require sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle  --no-update # optional
composer require friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle  --no-update # optional when using api
composer require nelmio/api-doc-bundle  --no-update # optional when using api
composer require sonata-project/google-authenticator --no-update  # optional
composer update
```

Check this links

- https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/index.html
- https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/security.html
- https://sonata-project.org/bundles/user/4-x/doc/reference/installation.html